# How to set associated domains for NFC background reading in iOS12

Tags: ios, xcode, core-nfc

I'm trying to set up my NFC Reader app to support the new background reading feature in iOS12:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading?changes=latest_minor

But I'm really struggling with the associated domains part.

> Next, enter the domain for each universal link supported by your app.

I tried adding the associated domain in different formats. For example:

```
mailto
mailto:
```

But I'm always getting this error from AppStoreConnect:

> App Store Connect Operation Error
>   ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'mailto' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/NFC Reader.app/NFC Reader' is not supported."

How do I set those associated domains correctly?

Comment: Your associated domains should be websites, not "mailto" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your associated domains should be websites, not "mailto" or something similar.

Comment: That is not true. Have you read the the guide for adding background nfc reading capabilities?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading mailto is listed under url schemes, not associated domains.

Comment: Yes, the document says nfc tag urls can either be a Universal Link, or a url like facetime:.. mailto:.. that are opened in the apps mentioned. It could be clearer about this distinction. It has example for Universal Link Entitlements though that isn't just unclear but contradictory & confusing: while it says "enter the domain for each universal link" with an example adding simply "example.com", documentation for Universal Links say they should be in the form "applinks:example.com". Do I add both? Why are Apple docs so unhelpful these days?